# Django url pattern string

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I would like to make a lists page with item such as `/lists` and have items such as `/lists/node-js` The url pattern I'm using is this -

`url(r'^lists/(?P<foo>[\w\-]+)/$', views.lists_template, name='lists_template'),`
but due to this `/lists` does not work and shows a page not found error.How do I solve this?

Comment: Replace the `+` with `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the **wrong quantifier**: in a regex, the **`+`** means *one or more*, whereas **`*`** means *zero or more*.

If you want to match the empty string as well, you thus need the `*` *quantifier*.

Furthermore we need to be able to make the last slash optional, since otherwise two slashes are required. So we can use the **`?`** quantifier which means *optional*.

```
url(r'^lists/(?P[\w\-]*)/?$', views.lists_template, name='lists_template'),
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it :)